# TSQL A recursive update?

Tags: t-sql, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm wondering if exists a recursive update in tsql (CTE)

```
ID  parentID value
--  -------- -----
1   NULL     0
2   1        0
3   2        0
4   3        0
5   4        0
6   5        0
```

I it possible to update the column `value` recursively using e.g CTE from ID = 6 to the top most row ?

Comment: what would you like to update it with?  is a procedureal loop ok? or is the requirement all in a single update statement?

Comment: I made a mistake, read again the last sentence

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it should be. [MSDN gives an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=SQL.90).aspx):

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
WITH DirectReports(EmployeeID, NewVacationHours, EmployeeLevel)
AS
(SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.VacationHours, 1
  FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
  WHERE e.ManagerID = 12
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.VacationHours, EmployeeLevel + 1
  FROM HumanResources.Employee as e
  JOIN DirectReports AS d ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID
)
UPDATE HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours * 1.25
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
JOIN DirectReports AS d ON e.EmployeeID = d.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: The CTE itself isn't updatable though. This gives the error `Derived table 'DirectReports' is not updatable because a column of the derived table is derived or constant.`

Comment: geez, of course... we can join the CTE table in the update query, that solves all my problems... I owe You a beer, man ;) thanks !

Comment: @Tony - don't bother. It'll be completely sufficient if you just accept my answer and henceforth refer to me as "Your Majesty". :)